# Deploy option missing after adding spfx webpart package to app catalog

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, app-catalog

In my new SP Online Team site(private group), I have got Site Collection level App Catalog enabled in the site.

I am able to upload SPFx web part package to the App Catalog. But unlike my other SP online team sites, the Pop-up to deploy the app is not coming. Moreover the options for Apps in the app catalog ribbon Files Tab("View Details Page", "Manage Installed Apps", "Deploy") are also not there.

As per my testing, there is no problem in the app package as it is getting deployed in other site collection's app catalog and working fine.

Can anyone please point what's wrong with this scenario and how to resolve this?

**Update: Attaching package-solution.json code**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/package-solution.schema.json",
  "solution": {
    "name": "my-app-client-side-solution",
    "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "version": "1.0.0.0",
    "includeClientSideAssets": true,
    "isDomainIsolated": false
  },
  "paths": {
    "zippedPackage": "solution/my-app.sppkg"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your package-solution.json code. Also do you see the deploy button on Ribbon disbaled after selecting the app in app catalog

Comment: We have same issue in our tenant and opened a case with Microsoft support. Its happening only for new sites created.

Comment: @AkshayRandive: No, as mentioned in the question, the button to deploy the app in the ribbon is not visible once I select the package in catalog. Also updated question with  `package-solution.json` code.

Comment: @Vishwa: Did you get any updates from Miscrosoft ? Is it resolved for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had same issue in our tenant and opened a case with Microsoft support.

Microsoft came back stating that user who enables the App catalog must be owner of the Site collection. Also, User must have SPO admin role and also admin of tenant app catalog site collection. It was not the case before, but they have changed the [Add-SPOSiteCollectionAppCatalog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/add-spositecollectionappcatalog?view=sharepoint-ps) cmdlet to work with below role/access requirements.

To run this cmdlet user must have the following roles:

- SharePoint Admin role or Global Administrator role
- Site Collection Administrator of the tenant app catalog
- Site Collection Administrator of the site collection of the site specified in the -Site parameter

Comment: Anybody have any luck with this fix?

Answer (score 0):

To add to Vishwa's answer (I don't have reputation required to comment) - if you used the m365 cli to add the site collection app catalog, what worked for me was:

- ensuring my admin account was Owner of the site collection. This can be done at `<your-tenant-url>-admin.sharepoint.com`
- removing the existing site collection app catalog using the m365 cli. Interestingly this didn't remove any of the files I'd uploaded, but disabled the catalog.
  `m365 spo site appcatalog remove --siteUrl <your-url-here>`
- add the app catalog again using the m365 cli:
  `m365 spo site appcatalog add --siteUrl <your-url-here>`

Deploy options then appeared.